# chart auto scales as you resizing the window (made with google web app)

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, google-visualization

I am trying to make a chart that resizes automatically when I change the size of the window. Let's say I have this code from the documentation: https://jsfiddle.net/r3ckg7ep/1/

documentation link: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/candlestickchart

code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Mon', 20, 28, 38, 45],
      ['Tue', 31, 38, 55, 66],
      ['Wed', 50, 55, 77, 80],
      ['Thu', 77, 77, 66, 50],
      ['Fri', 68, 66, 22, 15]
      // Treat first row as data as well.
    ], true);

    var options = {
      legend:'none'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.CandlestickChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

How can it be accomplished?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to re-draw the chart anytime there is a resize...

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```